# installing python 2.7.9 on conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda

Hello I need to create an anaconda environment with python version = 2.7.9. The issue is that there are no ways that I can install that python version using conda. The channels that I have doesnt provide me that version, is there a way in which I can install a specific version of python using conda giving the fact that my current channels doesnt provide me the required version?

Comment: Build it from source.

Answer (score 2):

There is an archived version available on the `free` channel. Try

```bash
conda create -n py279 -c free python=2.7.9
```